# "Missing sudo password" error with Ansible Error

Tags: ansible, elevated-privileges, sudoers

This is my simple playbook,

```
---
- name: test
  hosts: all
  tasks:
     - name: testing
       shell: /usr/bin/whoami
       register: testing

     - name: show the result
       debug:
          msg: "{{ testing.stdout }}"
```

When I try to use this using `user1` I get correct the expected output as `user1`.

However, my requirement is to run the shell command using a root user. something like sudo whoami.
So I modified the playbook like this.

```
---
- name: test
  hosts: all
  tasks:
     - name: testing
       shell: /usr/bin/whoami
       become: true
       register: testing

     - name: show the result
       debug:
          msg: "{{ testing.stdout }}"
```

However, I keep getting following error,

```
fatal: [xxxxxxxxx]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Missing sudo password"
}
```

Can anybody please help understand what I am missing here?

To allow the `user1` to run this as sudo root, I have added following entry in the sudoers file.

```
user1 ALL=(ALL:ALL) /usr/bin/whoami
```

Also, to avoid the providing `user1` password, I added following entry to the local `ansible.cfg`

```
[privilege_escalation]
become_ask_pass=False
```

Still getting the same error mentioned above.

Comment: Ansible ships Python code to your nodes and that is what is run as sudo, not the command as defined in the `shell` module, hence why Ansible specifically explain that [privilege escalation must be general](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html#privilege-escalation-must-be-general).

Comment: Best practice is `user1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response @VladimirBotka. Yes, user1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL works fine. But our security team is not agreeing to this. Do you know how to decide what all commands I need to add explicitly?

Comment: Point your security team to [Privilege escalation must be general](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html#privilege-escalation-must-be-general). Quoting: "You cannot limit privilege escalation permissions to certain commands. ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***`user1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` works fine. But our security team is not agreeing to this.***

An example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Execute
    shell:
      cmd: "id"
    register: output

  - debug:
      var: output
```

with an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ************************************************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  output:
    changed: true
    cmd: id
    delta: '0:00:00.014084'
    end: '2024-01-09 10:55:00.340407'
    failed: false
    msg: ''
    rc: 0
    start: '2024-01-09 10:55:00.326323'
    stderr: ''
    stderr_lines: []
    stdout: uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
    stdout_lines:
    - uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

shows with **`sudo tail -F /var/log/secure`** on the Remote Node

```bash
Jan  9 10:55:00 test.example.com sshd[32004]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.0.2.1 user=ansible_user
Jan  9 10:55:00 test.example.com sshd[32004]: Accepted password for ansible_user from 192.0.2.1 port 48984 ssh2
Jan  9 10:55:00 test.example.com sshd[32004]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ansible_user by (uid=0)
Jan  9 10:55:00 test.example.com sudo: ansible_user : TTY=pts/6 ; PWD=/home/ansible_user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS-<id> ; /usr/bin/python /home/ansible_user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-<timestamp>-<id>/AnsiballZ_<modulename>.py
Jan  9 10:55:00 test.example.com sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ansible_user(uid=0)
Jan  9 10:55:00 test.example.com sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

**To Summarize**

> ***How to decide what all commands I need to add explicitly?***

The command executed in the example was

```bash
/bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS-<id> ; /usr/bin/python /home/ansible_user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-<timestamp>-<id>/AnsiballZ_<modulename>.py
```

Therefore you could try to add in **`sudoers`** file a line at the end, like in  **`tail -1 /etc/sudoers`**

```bash
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

and under **`/ect/sudoers.d`** a file **`/etc/sudoers.d/ansible`**

```bash
ansible_user    ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: /bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS-* ; /usr/bin/python *
```

for Ansible Modules written in Python.

**Further Reading**

- [Multiple argument wildcard matches for `sudoers` file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/523235/266568)
- [Ansible module architecture - Ansiballz framework](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_program_flow_modules.html#ansiballz-framework)

Comment: Thanks a lot @U880D. This makes a lot sense. Let me try this out.

Comment: This resolved my issue. Thanks a lot once again for your prompt help!